# Can't find twitter DM textbox by xpath using selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath

I am trying to find the textbox element using the find_element_by_xpath() method, but It keeps telling me it cant find said element, here's the line of code that does that.

I've tried finding it by link_text, partial link text, selector and it just doesn't work

```
bar = nav.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/aside/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This selector seems to be very fragile, it's not a good price to copy XPath from developers tools. Which textbox you're trying to find?

Comment: @Lughzin Update the question with the relevant HTML.

Comment: @MarsilinouZaky I'm trying to get the textbox that has "Start a new message" written on it when you open a DM with someone over on twitter

Answer (score 1):

So, I suggest creating your xpath if you want to be precise and avoid taking it based on html structure (which can change).

The locators looks like:
[image]

And you can take it with xpath:

```
//input[@placeholder='Search people' and @role='combobox']
```

To avoid this problem, I suggest going trough a tutorial for a better understanding regarding how to create custom locators:  [Xpath tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Answer (score 0):

What was happening is: When I opened the tab to inspect the element, the DM structure changed because of my screen size so the xpath wasn't the same

Comment: is not because of the screen size, is because of application's mechanism designed to make front end code dynamic.

Comment: @Razvan Yes, that was exactly what was happening, sorry for not being able to word it correctly, I'm not very experienced with front end yet